# kusto how to check if the complete column does not have a specific string?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have a dataset that looks like this

[image]

I need to find the list of servers which never went to Healthy state in past 10 days.
Issue I am facing is if i write where State !contain Healthy then it its still taking server 1 and 2 as there is a record of state containing repair. So in short, how to find if the server does not have state as Healthy in the complete column?

Answer (score 3):

you could try using `countif()`:

```
T
| summarize c = countif(State == "Healthy") by ServerName
| where c == 0
```